# Show that $P_{1}=1$ and $P_{2}=P_{3}=\ldots=P_{n}=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $P_{1}, P_{2}, \ldots, P_{n}$ be polynomials in $x$, each having all integer coefficients, such that $P_{1}=P_{1}^{2}+P_{2}^{2}+\ldots+P_{n}^{2}$. Assume that $P_{1}$ is not the zero polynounial. Show that $P_{1}=1$ and $P_{2}=P_{3}=\ldots=P_{n}=0$.

---

## My attempt

As $P_{1}, P_{2}, \ldots, P_{n}$ are all polynomials with integer coefficients, so, $P_{1}^{2}+P_{2}^{2}+\ldots+P_{n}^{2}$ $ \geqslant$ $P_{1}$. What I should do after this?

Comment: Just look at the degrees.

Comment: @lulu by degree, do you mean that, I can directly say that the only solution for that equation is when $P_1$ is $1$? Can't we directly conclude it, as all of p1,p2,p3,.....pn has to be positive as it's squared and the only solution should just be $P_1=0$

Comment: Well, you have to have an argument for any of those claims.  What's the degree on the left?  What's the degree on the right?

Comment: @lulu The Right hand side has to be positive as itbis sum of squares. So $P_1$ has to be positive. But also, $P_1^{2} \geqslant  P_1$.  So for the both sides to be equal, $P_1=P_1^{2}$ . And the only way it would be is $1$. Is it correct?

Comment: Still needs an argument.    I wouldn't say that what you say is "obvious", or at least, it's not much more obvious than the original claim. Where are you using the fact that the coefficients are integers, for instance?

Comment: @lulu it's given in the question that the coefficients are integers

Comment: Yes, I asked where in your argument you use that fact.  The claim is false if you don't require integer coefficients (worth writing out a counterexample in that case).

Comment: @lulu  then if I just mention the argument given in my previous comments along with stating that the coefficients are integers, would that make my solution legible. Also, below, WhatsUp's solution uses the same idea. Would it be correct.

Comment: It's a question of how much detail is expected.  I would argue:  letting $d_i$ be the degree of $P_i$ we have $d_1=2d_1+2d_2+\cdots +2d_n\implies 0=d_1+2d_2+\cdots +2d_n\implies d_i=0\,\,\forall i$.  So all the polynomials are constant.  Now, for any integer $m$ we have $m^2≥m$ with equality only for $m\in \{0,1\}$.  Since $0$ is excluded we must have $P_1(x)=1$ and the rest follows at once.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your attempt:

For any integer value of $x$, we have $P_1(x)^2 \geq P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)^2 + \cdots + P_n(x)^2 \geq 0$. Thus the equality only holds when $P_1(x)^2 = P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x) = \cdots = P_n(x) = 0$.

This being true for any integer $x$, it is clear that $P_1 = 1$ and $P_2 = \cdots = P_n = 0$, under the assumption that $P_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed, it's not given that $x$ has to be an integer, so $x$ can even be complex, rational so we can't surely say $P_1(x)^{2} \geq P_1(x)$.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The inequalities hold for all integer values of $x$. If a polynomial evaluates to zero for all integer values of $x$, then it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: but it's not stated that $x$ has to integer, it only says that coefficients are integer, not $x$. $x$ can even be complex

Comment: The logic goes like this: if $x$ is an integer, then $P_2(x) = 0$. Since $P_2(x) = 0$ for any integer $x$, the polynomial $P_2$ is the zero polynomial. I don't know how to explain better, so if you still cannot understand then please ignore this answer.

Comment: well I do understand your logic and arguement but what I'm trying to say is different.  I am saying $x$ isn't neccesarily  an integer. Your solution is correct for integers but not from complex, real, rational etc.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my thinking,

We know that $P = P_1^2+P_2^2+...+P_n^2$ is a sum of polynomials, which is thus also polynomial (since a polynomial squared is polynomial).

This means that we can express $P$ as $P=a_0+a_1x+...+a_kx^k$, in this case $k=2n$.

We know that if $P_1 = P$ all the coefficients must be the same so we consider what these coefficients will be:

If $b_{xy}$ is the $y$th coefficient of $P_x$ i.e. $P_2 = b_{2,0}+b_{2,1}x+...+b_{2,n,}x^n$

$a_0 = b_{1,0}^2 + b_{2,0}^2 + ... b_{n,0}^2$

$a_1 = 2(b_{1,0}b_{1,1})+2(b_{2,0}b_{2,1})+...+2(b_{n,0}b_{n,1})$

and so on

Since all coefficients must be the same we can start with obtaining the solutions to of these equations, say $a_0 = b_{1,0}$

This means
$b_{1,0} = b_{1,0}^2 + b_{2,0}^2 + ... b_{n,0}^2$

Since these are all integers we can consider individual cases.

For $b_{1,0}>1$ or $b_{1,0} < 0$ The equation cannot be satisfied since

$b_{1,0} < b_{1,0}^2 \leq b_{1,0}^2 + b_{2,0}^2 + ... b_{n,0}^2$

For $b_{1,0}=1$ or $b_{1,0} = 0$:

$b_{1,0} = b_{1,0}^2 \leq b_{1,0}^2 + b_{2,0}^2 + ... b_{n,0}^2$

For equality all other coefficients must be zero:

$b_{i,0} = 0$ for $i>1$.

Now we consider the next equation $a_1 = b_{1,1}$:

$b_{1,1} = 2(b_{1,0}b_{1,1})+2(b_{2,0}b_{2,1})+...+2(b_{n,0}b_{n,1})$

Since we previously obtained $b_{1,0}=0 \text{ or } 1$ and all the other $b_{i,0} = 0$:

$b_{1,1} = 2b_{1,0}b_{1,1}$

For $b_{1,0} = 0, b_{1,1}$ can take any value. But I suspect this will cause a contradiction down the line.

For $b_{1,0} = 1, b_{1,1} = 0$, and so on.

This has not fully answered the question but I hope the setup helps with finishing. There is probably a more elegant proof somewhere.